# How do pass custom erl options for a Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My Phoenix app is hitting the Erlang VM's max process limit, what is the best way to specify custom options for erl (like +P) for a specific Phoenix app (or even better, only for MIX_ENV=PROD)? Is there a way to do this via the app's configuration files? Or if not, maybe when I run "mix phoenix.server"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `elixir` to run the application with the `--erl` flag:

```
elixir --erl "+P 10000000" -S mix phoenix.server
```

If you want a shell you can use `iex` instead:

```
iex --erl "+P 10000000" -S mix phoenix.server
```

Here is a copy of the usage for the elixir command.

> Usage: elixir [options] [.exs file] [data]
>
> -v                Prints version and exits
>     -e "command"      Evaluates the given command (*)
>
>     -r "file"         Requires the given files/patterns (*)
>     -S "script"       Finds and executes the given script
>     -pr "file"        Requires the given files/patterns in parallel (*)
>
>     -pa "path"        Prepends the given path to Erlang code path (*)
>     -pz "path"        Appends the given path to Erlang code path (*)
>
>     --app "app"       Start the given app and its dependencies (*)
>     --erl "switches"  Switches to be passed down to Erlang (*)
>     --name "name"     Makes and assigns a name to the distributed node
>     --sname "name"    Makes and assigns a short name to the distributed node
>     --cookie "cookie" Sets a cookie for this distributed node
>     --hidden          Makes a hidden node
>     --detached        Starts the Erlang VM detached from console
>     --werl            Uses Erlang's Windows shell GUI (Windows only)
>     --no-halt         Does not halt the Erlang VM after execution
>
> ** Options marked with (*) can be given more than once
>   ** Options given after the .exs file or -- are passed down to the executed code
>   ** Options can be passed to the Erlang runtime using ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS or --erl

If you are using `exrm` then you can also provide this in the `vm.args` file https://hexdocs.pm/exrm/release-configuration.html